# iterating through multiple list in a nested list

Tags: r, list

Say I have a list
`my_list <- c(1=c(23,35,46,72,81), 2= c(319,52,91,110), 3=c(67,101), 4=c(125,145,15))`

If I do-
`df <-  enframe(my_list)`  
I get an output of

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23,35,46,72,81 |
| 2 | 319,52,91,110 |

I would like to have something like-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 |
| 1 | 35 |
| 1 | 46 |
| 1 | 72 |

Ho do I get to this?

I tried`df <-  enframe(my_list)`
I get an output of

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23,35,46,72,81 |
| 2 | 319,52,91,110 |

I would like to have something like-

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 |
| 1 | 35 |
| 1 | 46 |
| 1 | 72 |

Comment: Note in your example you don't have a list, you have a named vector.  If you did have a list you could do `stack(my_list)`.

Comment: Hey Richie thanks for the suggestion. I got my df using stack.

Comment: `my_list <- c(1=c(23,35,46,72,81), 2= c(319,52,91,110), 3=c(67,101), 4=c(125,145,15))` fails. Did you mean `my_list <- c("1" = c(23,35,46,72,81), "2" =  c(319,52,91,110), "3" = c(67,101), "4" = c(125,145,15))`?

Comment: Yes. That was a fault on myside of displaying the list.

Comment: Thanks! `enframe(my_list)` doesn't return your first table for me. My output is:
`structure(list(name = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "31", "32", "41", "42", "43"), value = c(23, 35, 
46, 72, 81, 319, 52, 91, 110, 67, 101, 125, 145, 15)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row. Names = c(NA, -14L))`. The output does look useful though.